# Anime line on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, scroll

I have a simple animation (a line extend) and it's played automatically, but it's at the second section of the website. How can I make it appear when the user is on it?

Here is the code:

```css
#home {
 height:1000px;
 background:rgba(0,153,255,1);
}

#work {
 position:relative;
 height:1000px;
 background: rgba(0,204,102,1);
}

#about{
 height:1000px;
 background: rgba(153,51,51,1);
 
}

#contact {
 height:1000px;
 background: rgba(153,153,153,1);
 
}


#line{
    position:absolute;
 width:340px;
 margin-top:200px;
 height:4px;
 background:rgba(0,0,0,1);
   -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
      -moz-animation-name: slidein;
      -webkit-animation-name: slidein;
}

 @-moz-keyframes slidein {
      from {
        margin-left:100%;
        width:300%
      }
      
      to {
        margin-left:0%;
        width:600%;
      }
    }

 @-webkit-keyframes slidein {
      from {
        margin-left:0%;
        width:0%
      }
      
      to {
        margin-left:0%;
        width:340px;
      }
    }
```

```html
<div id="home"> 
    
  </div>
  <div id="work">
  <div id="line">
  </div>
 
</div>
  <div id="about">
  </div>
  <div id="contact"></div>
```

And how can I make it work in the other way too, I mean, when the user is scroll up the animation work again?

Comment: I think you need waypoint.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### CSS Only Solution

*have some conts :*

- It works on hovering the #work div, so whenever you move your mouse to this div, animation will fire.
- If you still don't scroll enough, you won't see it either.

  ```css
  #work:hover > #line {    
    -moz-animation-name: slidein;  
    -webkit-animation-name: slidein;  
    animation-name: slidein;  
  }
  ```

```css
#home {
  height: 1000px;
  background: rgba(0, 153, 255, 1);
}
#work {
  position: relative;
  height: 1000px;
  background: rgba(0, 204, 102, 1);
}
#work:hover > #line {
  -moz-animation-name: slidein;
  -webkit-animation-name: slidein;
  animation-name: slidein;
}
#about {
  height: 1000px;
  background: rgba(153, 51, 51, 1);
}
#contact {
  height: 1000px;
  background: rgba(153, 153, 153, 1);
}
#line {
  position: absolute;
  width: 340px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  height: 4px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
@-moz-keyframes slidein {
  from {
    margin-left: 100%;
    width: 300%
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 600%;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slidein {
  from {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 0%
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 340px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="home">

</div>
<div id="work">
  <div id="line">
  </div>

</div>
<div id="about">
</div>
<div id="contact"></div>
```

### jQuery Solution

```
function isScrolledIntoView(el) {
  var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
      docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height(),
      elTop = $(el).offset().top,
      elBottom = elTop+$(el).height();
  return ((elBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elTop >= docViewTop));
  }

$(window).on('scroll',function(e){
  if(isScrolledIntoView($('#line'))){
    $('#line').addClass('animation-line');
  }else{
    $('#line').removeClass('animation-line');
  }
});
```

```js
function isScrolledIntoView(el) {
  var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
    docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height(),
    elTop = $(el).offset().top,
    elBottom = elTop + $(el).height();
  return ((elBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elTop >= docViewTop));
}

$(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
  if (isScrolledIntoView($('#line'))) {
    $('#line').addClass('animation-line');
  } else {
    $('#line').removeClass('animation-line');
  }
});
```

```css
#home {
  height: 1000px;
  background: rgba(0, 153, 255, 1);
}
#work {
  position: relative;
  height: 1000px;
  background: rgba(0, 204, 102, 1);
}
#about {
  height: 1000px;
  background: rgba(153, 51, 51, 1);
}
#contact {
  height: 1000px;
  background: rgba(153, 153, 153, 1);
}
#line {
  position: absolute;
  width: 340px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  height: 4px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
.animation-line {
  -moz-animation-name: slidein;
  -webkit-animation-name: slidein;
  animation-name: slidein;
}
@-moz-keyframes slidein {
  from {
    margin-left: 100%;
    width: 300%
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 600%;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slidein {
  from {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 0%
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 340px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home"></div>
<div id="work">
  <div id="line"></div>
</div>
<div id="about"></div>
<div id="contact"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use javascript hover or something similare to get the current position, if the position matches your ciriteria, add a class with your animation

```
document.querySelector('#line').addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
this.classList.add("animation_class");
});
```

this also works with css hover, but the implementation could get sticky

```
#line {
    margin-left:100%;
    width:300%;
    transition: width 1s, margin-left 1s;
}

#line:hover {
    margin-left:0%;
    width:600%;
}
```

the transition will fire whenever you enter or leave the *#line* element

its also possible to fire if a hover occurs on a previous element thourgh sibling selectors:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors

Comment: no i dont want an hover the animation is playing automaticly i just want make it play when i scroll at his position

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this solution uses JS, since you'll have to track the window position to start the animation, it's quite simple, you can see it here:

```js
$(function() {

  window.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
    var top = this.scrollY,
      line = $('#line');

    if (top > 640) {
      line.addClass('animate-line');
    } else
      line.removeClass('animate-line');

  });

});
```

```css
#home {
  height: 1000px;
  background: rgba(0, 153, 255, 1);
}

#work {
  position: relative;
  height: 1000px;
  background: rgba(0, 204, 102, 1);
}

#about {
  height: 1000px;
  background: rgba(153, 51, 51, 1);
}

#contact {
  height: 1000px;
  background: rgba(153, 153, 153, 1);
}

#line {
  position: absolute;
  width: 340px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  height: 4px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
}

.animate-line {
  -moz-animation-name: slidein;
  -webkit-animation-name: slidein;
}

@-moz-keyframes slidein {
  from {
    margin-left: 100%;
    width: 300%
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 600%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slidein {
  from {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 0%
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 340px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home"></div>
<div id="work">
  <div id="line"></div>
</div>
<div id="about">
</div>
<div id="contact"></div>
```

Explaining:

I split your line css in two parts:

```
#line{
  position:absolute;
  width:340px;
  margin-top:200px;
  height:4px;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,1);
     -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
}

.animate-line {
     -moz-animation-name: slidein;
  -webkit-animation-name: slidein;
}
```

So you animation just will `fire` when you add the class `.animate-line`.

Then I add this JS:

```
$(function() {

  window.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
    var top = this.scrollY,
        line = $('#line');

    if(top > 640){
      line.addClass('animate-line');
    }else
      line.removeClass('animate-line');

  });

});
```

Quite simple too, it just tracks the `window.scrollY` and when the position is **> 640** it adds the class `.animate-line` so your animation starts!

Cheers